# redirect problem searchglassfilms.com to www.searchglassfilms.com using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain searchglassfilms.com, the problem which I'm facing is searchglassfilms.com isn't responding. How to redirect all the request for searchglassfilms.com to www.searchglassfilms.com? I know it can be done with .htaccess but I've not been able to find a solution till now.

> [searchglassfilms.com](http://searchglassfilms.com) is not working [www.searchglassfilms.com](http://www.searchglassfilms.com) is working why?

check here I have done something :

```
    # turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^[^.]*?\.?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.                         [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         http://www.%1/$1                [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.searchglassfilms\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$


# Redirect non-www to www

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    # If https send to https://www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If http send to http://www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^searchglassfilms.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.searchglassfilms.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

> can someone identify what's going wrong in .htaccess file which is on root directory?

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/977685/redirect-searchglassfilms-com-to-www-searchglassfilms-com-using-htaccess

Comment: i need solution.

Comment: Are you certain that the requests hit that host _at all_ and are actually responded to?

Comment: I don't know it, can you check? I can provide details